# protractor expect method returns an error while everything is working correctly

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I'm using a protractor to test an angular application. I was trying to get a text and compare it, but I got this weird error!

I have this line of code :

```
expect(warning.getText()).toEqual('The GLAccount or Number already exists.');
```

And the test failed with this message:

```
Expected ['The GLAccount or Number already exists.'] to equal 'The GLAccount or Number already exists.'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `warning` is an `ElementArrayFinder` (the result of `element.all()` or `$$()`). Instead, get a single element (`ElementFinder` instance):

```
expect(warning.first().getText()).toEqual('The GLAccount or Number already exists.');
```

Or, see how you defined `warning` and replace `element.all()` with `element()` if you are really looking for a single element.

Comment: Thank you!! That's was really helpful.

Comment: @adam great, please make sure to accept the answer to resolve the topic.

Comment: Thats a great guess !!